# ASTM Splitting and parsing data in c#

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to integrate lab. device with our his. I can get the message from the device, but i couldn't find a way to split the patient info and the results. here is the message that i got from the device:

```
<ENQ><STX>1H|\^&|||H7600^1|||||host|RSUPL^BATCH|P|1<CR>P|1|||||||U||||||^<CR>O|1|            mithat|0^50010^010^^S1^SC|^^^687^\^^^685^\^^^418^\^^^717^\^^^19^\^^^698^\^^^700^\^^^690^|R||||||N||||1|||||||20160430020618|||F<CR>C|1|I|                          <ETB>BE<CR><LF><STX>2    ^                         ^                    ^               ^          |G<CR>R|1|^^^687/|12.5|U/l||N||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|2|^^^685/|12.7|U/l||N||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|3|^^^418/|35.1|mg/dl||N||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|4|^^^<ETB>4D<CR><LF><STX>3717/|101.5|mg/dl||N||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|5|^^^19/|0.186|mg/dl||N||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|6|^^^698/|10.48|mg/dl||H||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|7|^^^700/|4.0|mg/dl||N||F||bmserv|||P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>R|8|^^^690/|0.67|mg/dl||L||F||bmserv||<ETB>C1<CR><LF><STX>4|P1<CR>C|1|I|0|I<CR>L|1|N<CR><ETX>44<CR><LF><EOT>
```

How can I split patien ID which is mitat in the code and the test codes with results which is like ^^^700/|4.0|mg/dl

Thank you ...

Comment: You did not post real data.  It is pseudo code.  STX is really a control character 0x01 and ETX is control character 0x02.  So your code needs to start reading data when you get the STX (start) and stop when you get ETX (end).  You need to read one line of data which ends with the <CR> which is really 0xC (return).  Then start parsing the data.

Comment: A part of data that I received from serial port is: \u00021H|\\^&|||H7600^1|||||host|RSUPL^REAL|P|1\rP|1|||||||U||||||^\rO|1|    colin james taylor|0^50011^011^^S1^SC|^^^435^\\^^^687^\\^^^685^\\^^^418^\\^^^59^\\^^^798^\\^^^717^\\^^^19^\\^^^690^\\^^^781^|R||||||N||||1|||||||20160427184217|||F\rC|1|I|            \u001783\r\n\u0004 But I don't know how to split patient data and test results with test codes.

Comment: The looks like H3 medical data which is normally in xml format.  It looks like fixed width column data,  I'm not sure if it is better to use a byte[] or a string when receiving this data.  With byte array you can use the generic Copy method : Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length).  With string use Substring method : Substring(int startIndex, int length)